# Changing color of a row after updating for 1 minute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter, CSS and JQuery. I want to change the background color of a row after 1 minute. After 1 minute of the updating action the row gets the default color like other rows.

Any idea, any function, can anyone help!

Thank you for any help.

Comment: [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

kickoff a `setTimeout` function when you have just updated the row

```
// maybe you could give the row a class such as .updated
var row = $('table tr.updated');
updateRow(row);

// or maybe the updated row is always the last one?
var row = $('table tr').last();
updateRow(row);

function updateRow(row)
{
    // do all the stuff associated with updating the row

    // note that you're going to actually have to find row yourself or
    // pass it in as an element

    $(row).css('background-color', 'red');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(row).css('background-color', your default color);
    }, 60000);
}
```

Comment: maybe this can help, but how can I pass the row to the given function

Comment: just updated my answer to include some ways to find it

Comment: Sir how to call the updateRow function from the controller in CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0):

You must use `setTimeout(function, miliseconds)`
For example:

```
function setColorTemporary(obj) {
    $(obj).css("background-color", "blue");
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        $(obj).css("background-color", "transparent");
    }, 60000); //60 seconds
}

setColorTemporary($("#id987")); //Set color for any object for 1 minute
```

In Controller, maybe...

```
<?php
class MyController extends CI_Controller {

    public function method()
    {
            $id = "#id987";
            echo "<script>setColorTemporary($('$id'));</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: this can help too sir, now how to assoiate the setColorTemporary funtion with the returned updated row, this can be injected in the controller update funtion, any help for the injection through the controller